# webpack html-webpack-plugin, can I use conditional comments to import entry script?

Tags: webpack

I have multiple entry like:

```
entry: {
  foo: 'foo.js'
  bar: 'bar.js'
  ie: 'ie.js'
},
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
  filename: '[name]-[hash].min.js'
}
```

when I use HtmlWebpackPlugin, It's for certain to import or not import an entry, using chunks.
I hope to generate conditional comments in HTML file, like:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ie-12dx....js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [jantimon](https://github.com/jantimon) - collaborator of html-webpack-plugin.

> You have to create a custom index file:
>   https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/default_index.html#L15

According to custom index file example, I made my own:

my scripts:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
{% for (var chunk in o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %}
{% if (/^ie-\w+\.min\.js$/.test(o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry)) { %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %}></script>
{% } %}
{% } %}
<![endif]-->
```

works great!